# Codeigniter dynamic url route mapping to a variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I have my routes.php as:

```
$route['logistics_park/(:num)']='user/logistics_park/$id';
```

Controller is:

```
public function logistics_park($id)
{ 
  echo $id;

}
```

I think that's how we catch the value of `(:num)` passed on the URL in the controller but when I `echo $id variable` I am getting "$id" as output.
I am getting the variable name as output mentioned in routes.
Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route should be like this

```
$route['logistics_park/(:num)'] = 'user/logistics_park/$1';
```

[URI Routing in Codeigniter.com](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples)

Comment: $1 also not helped.It only echoed $1.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need of `$id` in `routes.php` as `user/logistics_park/$id`. But you need some changes to the following statement. So change the following,

```
$route['logistics_park/(:num)']='user/logistics_park/$id';
```

to this.

```
$route['logistics_park/:id']='user/logistics_park';
```

The above statement defines a route update that accepts a parameter of id and points to the `logistics_park` method of the `user` class. You can `echo` the variable.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

Change the following in `autoload.php` line number 92

```
$autoload['helper'] = array();
```

to this

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file');
```

`autoload.php` will found in `application > config` folder